# Camel-Kafka security protocol SASL_SASL not working

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, sasl, confluent-cloud

Using as an starting point the official examples provided by Camel-Quarkus I have amended the logic in order to write to a Kafka broker. With the Camel Kafka component pointing to a **local broker** all **works well**.

Trying to reach our Confluent Cloud broker things become slightly more complicated. The security protocol we use is SASL_SSL. The following code snippet results in the logs added at the end of this question. In order to reproduce please find the complete code here https://github.com/LeonardoBonacci/camel-kafka-sasl

```
final String brokers = "the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud:9092";
final String saslJaasConfig = "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"USERNAME\" password=\"PASSWORD";

from("direct:start")
    .setBody(exchange -> "I do not arrive")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Sending to Kafka: ${body}")
    .to("kafka:foo-topic?" 
         + "brokers=" + brokers
         + "&saslMechanism=PLAIN"  
         + "&securityProtocol=SASL_SSL"
         + "&sslEndpointAlgorithm=HTTPS"
         + "&saslJaasConfig=" + saslJaasConfig);
```

The logged *ProducerConfig* seems correct. When I use the same credentials in a plain Kafka Producer, it - apart from writing records to the Kafka topic - prints an almost equal *ProducerConfig*. This suggests that the configuration values are well propagated to the underlying producer.

Interpreting the logs it seems that the SSL handshake works. Next step is less successful: a failing attempt of the *SaslClientAuthenticator*.

From various contradicting blogposts and the official documentation I cannot deduce on whether SASL_SSL is actually supported.

**Can anyone help me with this problem? Much appreciated!**

```
2020-11-02 07:16:03,244 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.sup.DefaultComponent] (Quarkus Main Thread) Creating endpoint uri=[direct://start], path=[start]
2020-11-02 07:16:03,246 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) direct://start converted to endpoint: direct://start by component: org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectComponent@28f69db6
2020-11-02 07:16:03,261 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) Resolving language: simple
2020-11-02 07:16:03,266 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.rei.LogReifier] (Quarkus Main Thread) LogName is not configured, using route id as logName: route1
2020-11-02 07:16:03,267 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.imp.con.CoreTypeConverterRegistry] (Quarkus Main Thread) Promoting fallback type converter as a known type converter to convert from: org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel to: java.lang.String for the fallback converter: org.apache.camel.impl.converter.EnumTypeConverter@1fecfc7b
2020-11-02 07:16:03,269 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) Using ComponentResolver: org.apache.camel.quarkus.core.FastCamelContext$$Lambda$693/0x0000000840394040@51356a7e to resolve component with name: kafka
2020-11-02 07:16:03,269 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.sup.ResolverHelper] (Quarkus Main Thread) Lookup Component with name kafka in registry. Found: org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaComponent@a614e14
2020-11-02 07:16:03,270 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.DefaultConfigurerResolver] (Quarkus Main Thread) Found configurer: kafka-component via type: org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaComponentConfigurer via: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/configurer/kafka-component
2020-11-02 07:16:03,270 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.DefaultConfigurerResolver] (Quarkus Main Thread) Found configurer: kafka-endpoint via type: org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaEndpointConfigurer via: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/configurer/kafka-endpoint
2020-11-02 07:16:03,272 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.sup.DefaultComponent] (Quarkus Main Thread) Creating endpoint uri=[kafka://foo-topic?brokers=the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud%3A9092&saslJaasConfig=xxxxxx&saslMechanism=PLAIN&securityProtocol=SASL_SSL&sslEndpointAlgorithm=HTTPS], path=[foo-topic]
2020-11-02 07:16:03,278 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) kafka://foo-topic?brokers=the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud%3A9092&saslJaasConfig=xxxxxx&saslMechanism=PLAIN&securityProtocol=SASL_SSL&sslEndpointAlgorithm=HTTPS converted to endpoint: kafka://foo-topic?brokers=the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud%3A9092&saslJaasConfig=xxxxxx&saslMechanism=PLAIN&securityProtocol=SASL_SSL&sslEndpointAlgorithm=HTTPS by component: org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaComponent@a614e14
2020-11-02 07:16:03,282 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.sup.EventHelper] (Quarkus Main Thread) Ignoring notifying event Initialized CamelContext: camel-1. The EventNotifier has not been started yet: org.apache.camel.quarkus.core.CamelManagementEventBridge@7650b836
2020-11-02 07:16:03,282 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.sup.EventHelper] (Quarkus Main Thread) Ignoring notifying event Initialized CamelContext: camel-1. The EventNotifier has not been started yet: org.apache.camel.quarkus.core.CamelContextRuntime$1@519e862a
2020-11-02 07:16:03,283 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) Resolving language: simple
2020-11-02 07:16:03,285 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) Apache Camel 3.6.0 (camel-1) is starting
2020-11-02 07:16:03,287 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) Using ClassResolver=org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultClassResolver@35084cf5, PackageScanClassResolver=org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver@2b7ebe50, ApplicationContextClassLoader=null, RouteController=org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRouteController@5bfb4540
2020-11-02 07:16:03,289 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
2020-11-02 07:16:03,289 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) Using HeadersMapFactory: org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultHeadersMapFactory@1ae00ddf
2020-11-02 07:16:03,290 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) Using ReactiveExecutor: org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor@1621a5c3
2020-11-02 07:16:03,290 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) Using ThreadPoolFactory: org.apache.camel.support.DefaultThreadPoolFactory@205f397
2020-11-02 07:16:03,293 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.InternalRouteStartupManager] (Quarkus Main Thread) Warming up route id: route1 having autoStartup=true
2020-11-02 07:16:03,304 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.cli.pro.ProducerConfig] (Quarkus Main Thread) ProducerConfig values:
        acks = 1
        batch.size = 16384
        bootstrap.servers = [the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud:9092]
        buffer.memory = 33554432
        client.dns.lookup = default
        client.id = producer-1
        compression.type = none
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
        enable.idempotence = false
        interceptor.classes = []
        key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        linger.ms = 0
        max.block.ms = 60000
        max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
        max.request.size = 1048576
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retries = 0
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism = PLAIN
        security.protocol = SASL_SSL
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = HTTPS
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
        transactional.id = null
        value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

2020-11-02 07:16:03,515 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.aut.AbstractLogin] (Quarkus Main Thread) Successfully logged in.
2020-11-02 07:16:03,585 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.ssl.SslEngineBuilder] (Quarkus Main Thread) Created SSL context with keystore null, truststore null, provider SunJSSE.
2020-11-02 07:16:03,622 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.cli.pro.int.Sender] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Starting Kafka producer I/O thread.
2020-11-02 07:16:03,623 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.uti.AppInfoParser] (Quarkus Main Thread) Kafka version: 2.5.0
2020-11-02 07:16:03,625 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initialize connection to node the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request
2020-11-02 07:16:03,625 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.uti.AppInfoParser] (Quarkus Main Thread) Kafka commitId: 66563e712b0b9f84
2020-11-02 07:16:03,630 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.uti.AppInfoParser] (Quarkus Main Thread) Kafka startTimeMs: 1604254563622
2020-11-02 07:16:03,635 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating connection to node the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) using address the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud/123.123.123.123
2020-11-02 07:16:03,636 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.cli.pro.KafkaProducer] (Quarkus Main Thread) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Kafka producer started
2020-11-02 07:16:03,636 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.com.kaf.KafkaProducer] (Quarkus Main Thread) Created KafkaProducer: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@1939e92
2020-11-02 07:16:03,644 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.BaseExecutorServiceManager] (Quarkus Main Thread) Created new ThreadPool for source: kafka://foo-topic?brokers=the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud%3A9092&saslJaasConfig=xxxxxx&saslMechanism=PLAIN&securityProtocol=SASL_SSL&sslEndpointAlgorithm=HTTPS with name: KafkaProducer[foo-topic]. -> org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.RejectableThreadPoolExecutor@4a80dbc9[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0][KafkaProducer[foo-topic]]
2020-11-02 07:16:03,646 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.InternalRouteStartupManager] (Quarkus Main Thread) Route: route1 >>> Route[direct://start -> null]
2020-11-02 07:16:03,646 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.InternalRouteStartupManager] (Quarkus Main Thread) Starting consumer (order: 1000) on route: route1
2020-11-02 07:16:03,648 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.sup.DefaultConsumer] (Quarkus Main Thread) Init consumer: Consumer[direct://start]
2020-11-02 07:16:03,648 DEBUG [org.apa.cam.sup.DefaultConsumer] (Quarkus Main Thread) Starting consumer: Consumer[direct://start]
2020-11-02 07:16:03,649 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.InternalRouteStartupManager] (Quarkus Main Thread) Route: route1 started and consuming from: direct://start
2020-11-02 07:16:03,652 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
2020-11-02 07:16:03,652 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) Apache Camel 3.6.0 (camel-1) started in 0.365 seconds
2020-11-02 07:16:03,655 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) sasl 1.0 on JVM (powered by Quarkus 1.9.0.Final) started in 2.528s.
2020-11-02 07:16:03,656 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2020-11-02 07:16:03,661 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Installed features: [camel-core, camel-direct, camel-kafka, camel-support-common, cdi]
2020-11-02 07:16:03,661 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.aut.SaslClientAuthenticator] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Set SASL client state to SEND_APIVERSIONS_REQUEST
2020-11-02 07:16:03,662 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.aut.SaslClientAuthenticator] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Creating SaslClient: client=null;service=kafka;serviceHostname=the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud;mechs=[PLAIN]
2020-11-02 07:16:03,672 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.net.Selector] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 65536, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
2020-11-02 07:16:03,740 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Completed connection to node -1. Fetching API versions.
2020-11-02 07:16:03,859 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.net.SslTransportLayer] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud/123.123.123.123:9092], selector=sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@652ed71e, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSL handshake completed successfully with peerHost 'the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud' peerPort 9092 peerPrincipal 'CN=*.ap-southeast-2.aws.confluent.cloud' cipherSuite 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384'
2020-11-02 07:16:03,895 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.aut.SaslClientAuthenticator] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Set SASL client state to RECEIVE_APIVERSIONS_RESPONSE
2020-11-02 07:16:03,935 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.aut.SaslClientAuthenticator] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Set SASL client state to SEND_HANDSHAKE_REQUEST
2020-11-02 07:16:03,936 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.aut.SaslClientAuthenticator] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Set SASL client state to RECEIVE_HANDSHAKE_RESPONSE
2020-11-02 07:16:03,974 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.aut.SaslClientAuthenticator] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Set SASL client state to INITIAL
2020-11-02 07:16:03,977 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.aut.SaslClientAuthenticator] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Set SASL client state to INTERMEDIATE
2020-11-02 07:16:05,155 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.aut.SaslClientAuthenticator] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Set SASL client state to FAILED
2020-11-02 07:16:05,155 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.net.Selector] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Failed authentication with the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud/123.123.123.123 (Authentication failed)
2020-11-02 07:16:05,160 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2020-11-02 07:16:05,160 ERROR [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud/123.123.123.123:9092) failed authentication due to: Authentication failed
2020-11-02 07:16:05,161 WARN  [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2020-11-02 07:16:05,261 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
2020-11-02 07:16:05,311 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initialize connection to node the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request
2020-11-02 07:16:05,311 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating connection to node the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) using address the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud/123.123.123.123
2020-11-02 07:16:05,314 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.aut.SaslClientAuthenticator] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Set SASL client state to SEND_APIVERSIONS_REQUEST
2020-11-02 07:16:05,317 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.aut.SaslClientAuthenticator] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Creating SaslClient: client=null;service=kafka;serviceHostname=the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud;mechs=[PLAIN]
2020-11-02 07:16:05,349 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.net.Selector] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 65536, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
2020-11-02 07:16:05,357 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Completed connection to node -1. Fetching API versions.
2020-11-02 07:16:05,400 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.net.SslTransportLayer] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud/123.123.123.123:9092], selector=sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@652ed71e, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSL handshake completed successfully with peerHost 'the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud' peerPort 9092 peerPrincipal 'CN=*.ap-southeast-2.aws.confluent.cloud' cipherSuite 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384'
2020-11-02 07:16:05,400 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.aut.SaslClientAuthenticator] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Set SASL client state to RECEIVE_APIVERSIONS_RESPONSE
2020-11-02 07:16:05,440 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.aut.SaslClientAuthenticator] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Set SASL client state to SEND_HANDSHAKE_REQUEST
2020-11-02 07:16:05,441 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.aut.SaslClientAuthenticator] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Set SASL client state to RECEIVE_HANDSHAKE_RESPONSE
2020-11-02 07:16:05,476 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.aut.SaslClientAuthenticator] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Set SASL client state to INITIAL
2020-11-02 07:16:05,477 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.aut.SaslClientAuthenticator] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Set SASL client state to INTERMEDIATE
2020-11-02 07:16:06,722 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.aut.SaslClientAuthenticator] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Set SASL client state to FAILED
2020-11-02 07:16:06,722 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.net.Selector] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Failed authentication with the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud/123.123.123.123 (Authentication failed)
2020-11-02 07:16:06,724 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2020-11-02 07:16:06,724 ERROR [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud/123.123.123.123:9092) failed authentication due to: Authentication failed
2020-11-02 07:16:06,727 WARN  [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2020-11-02 07:16:06,824 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
2020-11-02 07:16:06,876 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
2020-11-02 07:16:06,927 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
2020-11-02 07:16:06,978 DEBUG [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
2
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the dsl does the trick:

```
kafka(topic)
           .brokers(props.getProperty("bootstrap.servers"))
           .saslMechanism(props.getProperty("sasl.mechanism")) 
           .securityProtocol(props.getProperty("security.protocol"))
           .sslEndpointAlgorithm(props.getProperty("ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm"))
           .saslJaasConfig(props.getProperty("sasl.jaas.config")))
```

Answer (score 4):

First, ensure your `saslJaasConfig`:

1. Has a username surrounded by escaped doublequotes, or single quotes:

   `required username=\"USERNAME\"` OR `required username='USERNAME'`
2. Has a password surrounded by escaped doublequotes, or single quotes:

   `password=\"PASSWORD\"` OR `password='PASSWORD'`
3. Ends with a `;`

   `String saslJaasConfig = "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"USERNAME\" password=\"PASSWORD\";";`

**Important:**
If the password has special characters, this can cause issues as Camel's string parser can confuse these special characters with additional arguments in the route. If your password contains these, you can denote the `saslJaasConfig` to be [RAW](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html#HowdoIconfigureendpoints-Configuringparametervaluesusingrawvalues):

`String saslJaasConfig = "RAW(org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"USERNAME\" password=\"PASSWORD\";)";`

In my case, this resolved the issue. It also explains why using the DSL could have resolved this issue - with the DSL, the values are set declaratively and no string parsing is required.

Comment: Very important!! this point that you said "If your password contains special characters, you must denote the saslJaasConfig to be RAW" otherwise you'll have Authentication failed. It help me to resolve an error of authentication failed that was working before. It was due that I generate a new password that contains special caracters.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is there with truststore file, you have to mention the truststore file at client side, please check **sslTruststoreLocation** attribute only

```
Eg: sslTruststoreLocation=E:\\test\\kafka.client.truststore.jks
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! From what I can see the SSL handshake is successful. The following log line suggests that ```SSL handshake completed successfully with peerHost 'the-kafka-host.confluent.cloud' peerPort 9092 peerPrincipal 'CN=*.ap-southeast-2.aws.confluent.cloud' cipherSuite 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384'```