# camel kafka producer exception Login module control flag is not available in the JAAS config

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel

i am consuming from mqtt through camel and trying to publish to confluent kafka, but when i produce to kafka i get the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Login module control flag is not available in the JAAS config
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasConfig.loginModuleControlFlag(JaasConfig.java:85) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasConfig.parseAppConfigurationEntry(JaasConfig.java:111) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
```

my camel config for building route uri looks like this

```
       builder.setScheme("kafka");
       builder.setHost(topicName);
       builder.setParameter("brokers",broker);
       builder.setParameter("saslMechanism","PLAIN");
       builder.setParameter("securityProtocol","SASL_SSL");
       builder.setParameter("saslJaasConfig", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"username\" password=\"Password\";");
```

i followed this link [Camel-Kafka security protocol SASL_SASL not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64635940/camel-kafka-security-protocol-sasl-sasl-not-working) tried to put JAAS config in RAW but it doesn't work, even i tried to externalize the jaas property as mentioned here
[Kafka "Login module not specified in JAAS config"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756543/kafka-login-module-not-specified-in-jaas-config) but still i am getting the same error not sure what is missing in jaas config or its a problem with camel kafka dependency

i am using following dependency chart camel version 2.25.4

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-mqtt</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

i have been stuck figuring out, any help?

Answer (score 2):

After some debuggiing i found that it works when i set up KafkaComponent in camel context , i set up properties in app.properties then i used KafkaComponent and set it in camel context it was able to take properties, but strangely while building uri i used the same property it didn't worked looks like camel is not able to read property from string uri in my case

```
        KafkaComponent kafka = new KafkaComponent();
        KafkaConfiguration kafkaConfiguration = new KafkaConfiguration();
        kafkaConfiguration.setBrokers(kafkaBrokerUrl);
        kafkaConfiguration.setSaslMechanism(saslmechanism);
        kafkaConfiguration.setSecurityProtocol(saslprotocol);
        kafkaConfiguration.setSaslJaasConfig(kafkajaasconfig);

        kafka.setConfiguration(kafkaConfiguration);

        getContext().addComponent("kafka", kafka);
```